# What are all of these numbers following the expected output?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I was trying to write a program to take an input and output the reverse of that input; here was my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int num[n];
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
    }
    for (int i=n; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cout << num[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I realized that in the second `for` loop, `i` can equal `0` and then `i` equals `-1`. However, the outputs don't really make sense. For example, an input of

```
6
8 1 2 6 3 9
```

results in

```
9 3 6 2 1 8 8 8
```

and a lot of the time it's just the array reversed but with an `8` added onto the end, but sometimes there are these types of numbers:

```
9
1 0 2 8 1 4 2 9 8
8 9 2 4 1 8 2 0 1 1703936
```

Where do these ending numbers come from? Because I don't understand what's going on, I can't generalize what the problem is, but if you have an easily-accessible IDE nearby and will copy and paste my code (assuming it's not a well-known problem and I'm making everyone laugh at my stupidity), could anyone tell me why there are these numbers added onto the end?

Comment: Because arrays are origin 0, loops like `for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)` almost always go wrong. Prefer `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` unless you have a really good reason to suffer the extra pain.

Comment: Let me ask you this: If the size of an array is `n`, what is the lat valid index in the array?  Where do you for loops end and start at?

Comment: Note: `int num[n];`, where `n` is non-constant expression, is non-standard C++.

Comment: Unrelated: Careful with `int num[n];`. It's not Standard C++ and not all compilers (including possibly the person marking the assignment) will accept it. It is also an excellent way to run a program out of Automatic Storage. Specify an `n` of, say, 5,000,000 and the program break will probably break.

Comment: @user4581301 What would be the standard?

Comment: Currently the [Standard is C++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/). This is due to change shortly as C++20 rolls out. Note the link is as close to C++17 as I can freely link to, but not exactly C++17.

Comment: @user4581301 You meant that `int num[n]` is not standard C++, right? I thought you meant that there is a standard way to take an input of more than one integer and put that in an array, so that is what I meant by, "What would be the standard?". Sorry if it was unclear.

Comment: Clearly I wasn't clear enough either. The intent was don't dimension arrays with variables. You can't count on a the functionality exiting AND it is dangerous to use.  Use `std::vector` instead if you're permitted to. If you aren't permitted to use `std::vector` write your own variable length array class because it is often easier to do than building ad-hoc code into a program.

Comment: There are a bunch of quick ways to read into a `vector`. `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(num));` will read `cin` until there are no more numbers, but when you know the number of numbers to be read, it's hard to beat a simple `for` loop.

Comment: Example: https://ideone.com/Qy5QT0 Note how easy reversing the array is with the reverse_iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

In C++, array indexes are **0-indexed**. This means if your array is size `n`, the valid indexes are `0, 1, 2, ..., n-1`.

Your loop will loop over `1, 2, 3, ..., n`. Do you see the issue? You never write to the 0'th index, and you write one past the last index (which is not allowed).

Then when you go to print:

```
for (int i=n; i>=0; i--)
```

You print `n, n-1, n-2, ..., 0`. You're printing the `n`'th element, which is again, not allowed.

Instead, your loops should look like:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin >> num[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << num[n - i - 1] << " ";
}
```

Comment: You could also use `int i = n - 1; i >=0; i--` for the second loop.

Comment: In my previous answer above, I failed to notice the *second* bug which eagle-eyed scohe001 caught!

Comment: @SolomonUcko that'd work here since we're using integers. But ideally these would be `size_t` types since we're talking about indexes (in which case `n - 1` would be underflow if `n` is 0). You're completely right here, but my old habits die hard :p

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop begins with `i` *equal to* `n` ... but that's not a valid array index, because an array containing *n* elements has indexes `[0..n-1]`!  Therefore, you are seeing "memory garbage."

So, your second loop should be:

`for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think that arrays are indexed from 1 which is your main issue.

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
```

The last element of an array if `length-1`, so if you had 3 elements the last index is 2, not 3; however, the loop above starts at 1 (the second element) and then accesses an index out of bounds, which is undefined behaviour.

But really you don't need to use indices at all, just `for (auto& i : n)` will iterate properly over your container. If you want to loop using indices, you need

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // forwards 
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) //backwards
```

It's worth noting that variable length arrays (that is, arrays whose lengths are not known at compile time) are not standard C++, but are an extension of GCC. It would be worth ditching that behaviour now, and using `vector` instead:

```
int length = 0;
std::cin >> length;
std::vector<int> n(length);
```